Creating web component / element in Angular does not work
I'm currently trying to create an Angular custom element / web component and integrate the web component in my ZK application. To start with an easy example, I just created a simple component that outputs a line of text.
zk.component.ts
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-zk',
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './zk.component.html',
  styleUrl: './zk.component.css'
})
export class ZkComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'Angular19';
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

zk.component.html:
<label>Hi, this is my first {{ title }} component to import into ZK</label>

The app.module.ts:
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { ZkComponent} from './zk/zk/zk.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ZkComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const zkTestElement = createCustomElement(ZkComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('zk-test', zkTestElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}

I create the bundle via  ng build --configuration production --output-hashing=none and a polyfills.js and main.js is created along with a index.html that loads both files:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-beasties-container>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular19</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
  <zk-test></zk-test>
<script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>

When I access the index.html in a browser, I get this error in the console:
main.js:7  SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "zktest" is not a valid custom element name
    at Mt.n.<computed> [as define] (polyfills.js:2:4356)
    at new e (main.js:7:108982)
    at Object.ɵfac [as useFactory] (main.js:7:109054)
    at Object.r [as factory] (main.js:7:5078)
    at Rt.hydrate (main.js:7:4221)
    at Rt.get (main.js:7:3406)
    at sl (main.js:4:2392)
    at S (main.js:4:2468)
    at useValue (main.js:7:1609)
    at Rt.resolveInjectorInitializers (main.js:7:3781)

Any idea where I could have gone the wrong way?

please share main.ts and app.component.ts

Found my error, will post some code later.

please post it as an answer instead I will upvote! it makes it simpler for the future reader to understand

Edit: OK, in the meantime I have found what was wrong with my code. Looks like I followed an outdated tutorial and the error was in app.module.ts. The code that instantiated the element had to go to the ngDoBootstrap() block and not to the constructor which is what they showed in the tutorial.
P.S. Please note that I had changed the element name in the process, so that was not the error. The name was always consistent.
This is how it is working:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppComponent,
    ZkComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap{
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const zkElement = createCustomElement(ZkComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('zk-widget', zkElement);
  }
}


The issue is likely caused by a mismatch between the custom element name defined in your code and the one used in the index.html. The error states that zktest is not a valid custom element name, while your index.html uses zk-test.

Good to know you found the problem, you can ignore this comment.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
